# Extract rows according to consecutive value pattern from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame, d:

```
d<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), var=c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes"))
```

I'd like to return all "no" rows for each ID leading up to a "yes" and including the first "yes".

desired result:

```
id var
1  no
1  no
1  no
1 yes
2  no
2 yes
3  no
3 yes
```

Comment: I tried using diff() but knew there had to be an easier solution. I'll mark the below as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joran indicates, it's polite to include what you've tried. It also increases the likelihood your question will get votes. This question is basic enough that even a rudimentary understanding of R could arrive at something.

In any case, this will do what you want:

```
d[! duplicated(d) | d$var == 'no', ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to stop forgetting about duplicated.